# How can i make a live template that write a method in an interface and implement it in implemention of this interface in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, interface, live-templates

I want to make a live template in intellij that write a method in an interface and implelemnt it in the implemention class of this interface. how can i do this?

Comment: It seems there is no way to do that but you can create a live template that generates a method, and perform `Alt + Enter | Implement method "name"` on a method signature after applying the template.

Comment: What did you tried so far?